# How can I aggregate data in Time Series Insights preview using the hierarchy?

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I am storing 15 minute electricity consumption measurements in a TSI preview environment. Is it possible to aggregate the total energy consumption per day of multiple meters using the TSI query API?

I have configured a hierarchy as Area-Building and the Time Series ID is the 'MeterId' of the Meter. 
The query API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/preview-query#aggregate-series-api) enabled me to aggregate to consumption per day for a single meter. Then I expected to find an API to aggregate the electricity consumption to Building and Area, but could only find the aggregate operation with a single "timeSeriesId" or "timeSeriesName" as required parameter. Is aggregation to a level in the hierarchy not possible? If not, what would be a good alternative (within or outside TSI) to obtain these aggregated values?

Comment: Did you consider using a [Compound key pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns#compound-key-pattern)? Use for TimeSeriesID something like: "meter1BuildingA", "meter2BuildingA", "meter3BuildingB"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not sure how to use it with TSI. How could I retrieve the values from both meters in BuildingA, aggregated by TSI? The example in your link uses the 'ge' (greater or equal) and  'lt' (less than) operators of the Table Storage API, but I could not find anything similar for TimeSeriesID in TSI API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may do, is get all the instances you need with the search api([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/preview-model#search)).(mind that the documentation is wrong for the 
url, it should contain "search" instead of "suggest" like this:
[image: correct url for searching through the models]) 
Then loop through the instances you get in the response to call the aggregates by id one by one. And finally sum the results yourself to have a daily result for all the telemetry sensors responding to your search.

Note: You can only make 9 aggregate calls at the same time([limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/preview-query#limits)).

I hope they fix aggregates soon.
In the meanwhile I hope it helps you out.

Good luck,

Comment: Not what I hoped for, but a workable solution for me. Thanks.